# Clearing last JSON response

Tags: javascript, ios, json, titanium-mobile

I am developing an iOS 6.1 app using Titanium Studio, build: 3.1.2.201307091805, I am testing on the iPhone simulator and iPad device. I have a search field that gets JSON results from a remote server. The screen I am having issues with has the search box at the top and a couple of messages below. When the user types in the search field and hits return, the messages are hidden and a table is placed ready to receive the results from the database. All of that is working fine. When the user types in something that is not in the database I have a message appear "No results found, please try again". I made a button to "Clear" the table or "Not Found" message. Here is the button code I have so far:

```
var clear = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title: "Clear",
    style:Titanium.UI.iPhone.SystemButtonStyle.BORDERED
});
clear.addEventListener("click", function() {
message.hide();
table.setData([]);
});
Ti.UI.currentWindow.setRightNavButton(clear);
```

This code does clear the message or the results in the table but when I do another search the previous result appears above the new result even if the searches were totally unrelated. Here is my code.

```
   var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;
    win.backgroundImage='images/background.png';
    win.barColor='#28517A';
    win.title='Product Search';

        var message = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text: 'No results found, please try again',
        top:'100dp',
        left:'20dp',
        right:'20dp'
    });

var customSearchBar = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor: '#28517A',
    height: 42,
    top: '0dp',
    width: Ti.UI.FILL
});

var customSearchField = Ti.UI.createTextField({
    autocorrect: false,
    borderStyle: Ti.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
    clearOnEdit: true,
    height: 28,
    hintText: 'Search For Product or Service',
    textAlign: 'center',
    width: '90%',
});
customSearchBar.add(customSearchField);

win.add(customSearchBar);

var nolist= Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text: 'XXXXXX',
        color: '#000',
        font: {fontSize:'16dp', fontWeight:'bold'},
        top:'50dp',
        left:'20dp',
        right:'20dp'
    });
    win.add(nolist);

    var businessowner = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text: 'XXXXXX',
        color: '#000',
        font: {fontSize:'16dp', fontWeight:'bold'},
        bottom:'10dp',
        left:'20dp',
        right:'20dp'
});
win.add(businessowner);

var view = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    top: '100dp',
    bottom:'60dp'   
});
var table = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    top: '0dp',
    height:'auto',
    bottom:'0dp'
});
view.add(table);
table.show();

var tableData = [];

function checkInternetConnection(){
return Ti.Network.online ? true : false;
}
customSearchField.addEventListener("return", function(e) {

    if(checkInternetConnection()){
    nolist.hide();
    businessowner.hide();
    getdata();
win.add(view);

function getdata(){
var url = "http://mydomain.com/filename.php?title="+e.value;

var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload: function() {
    Ti.API.debug(this.responseText);

var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

if (json.cms_list.length< 1){ 

    win.add(message);
}

    for (i = 0; i < json.cms_list.length; i++) {
        client = json.cms_list[i];
        row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
            height:'44dp',
            hasChild:true
        });

   var clientlist = Ti.UI.createLabel({
            text:client.clientname,
            font:{fontSize:'16dp', fontWeight:'bold'},
        height:'auto',
        left:'10dp',
        color:'#000'
        });

     row.add(clientlist);
        tableData.push(row);
        }

table.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    var row = e.row;
    var clientlist = row.children[0];
    var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        url: 'clientdetail.js', 
        title: clientlist.text  
    }); 
            var clientlist = clientlist.text;
                win.clientlist = clientlist;

            customSearchField.blur();   
    Titanium.UI.currentTab.open(win,{animated:true});}); 
    table.setData(tableData);
    },

    onerror: function(e) {
    Ti.API.debug("STATUS: " + this.status);
    Ti.API.debug("TEXT:   " + this.responseText);
    Ti.API.debug("ERROR:  " + e.error);
    alert('There was an error retrieving the remote data. Try again.');
    },
    timeout:5000

});

xhr.open("GET", url);
xhr.send();
}
}
else{
    alert('Your internet connection is not available');
}
});
    var clear = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title: "Clear",
    style:Titanium.UI.iPhone.SystemButtonStyle.BORDERED
});
clear.addEventListener("click", function() {
    message.hide();
    table.setData([]);
});
Ti.UI.currentWindow.setRightNavButton(clear);
```

If I press my back button and then return to this screen, the search is fine. How can I completely clear the previous results without leaving the screen and then returning?

Comment: Are you adding a new table each time?

Comment: Josiah, as I look at my code, I think I do by using the `table.setData([]);` followed by `table.setData(tableData);` and the `view.add(table);`. The first request removes messages and adds the table. When the "Clear" button is pushed, I try to clear all the data with `table.setData([]);` Is there something besides `table.setData([]);' that will remove all reference to the previous query?

Comment: Well, make sure you are only calling `view.add(table)` one time. Otherwise you will  get weird results like you are seeing.

Comment: Josiah, thank you so much for your assistance! I commented out the messages on the screen and moved adding my view to outside the functions to make sure I was only adding the table one time. There was no change in my results so I put the messages back in. I edited the code above to include most of the code in the file hoping you would look at it to see if you could identify my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the table to the window every time you click "return". Change your event listener by removing `win.add(view);` from it, and replace that line with `table.show();` like this:

```
customSearchField.addEventListener("return", function(e) {

    if(checkInternetConnection()){
    nolist.hide();
    businessowner.hide();
    getdata();
    //win.add(view); dont do this!!!!
    table.show();
.....
});
```

Then, change this:

```
var table = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    top: '0dp',
    height:'auto',
    bottom:'0dp'
});
view.add(table);
//table.show(); 
win.add(table);
table.hide();
```

Now you will only have one instance of a table, and you can use setData inside the return listener every time you want to change all the rows.

Comment: Thank you Josiah, showing and hiding the table is much better than creating a new table each time. BUT, I am still experiencing the same problem. The first query works correctly, but even when I clear out the table using my "Clear" button, every query result from every previous query appears in the table in the order I queried them. If I go back to the window before this search window, all queries are cleared and I can start fresh. Any idea what else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

You are not clearing data from `var tabledata`. It should be cleared when you are setting `table.setData([]);` . It is pushing the same data after setting the table as empty.

Your code should look like this:

```
clear.addEventListener("click", function() {
  message.hide();
  tableData = [];
  table.setData([]);
});
```